# emacs org-mode error during installation in windows

Tags: org-mode, microsoft-windows, debugging

While I try to install org-mode using `M-x package-install RET org RET`, I am getting the following error. I am new to both emacs and org-mode and using Windows 10.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function org-link-set-parameters)
  (org-link-set-parameters "file+emacs")
  (progn (org-link-set-parameters "file+emacs") (org-link-set-parameters "file+sys"))
  (closure (t) nil (progn (org-link-set-parameters "file+emacs") (org-link-set-parameters "file+sys")))()
  eval-after-load(org (closure (t) nil (progn (org-link-set-parameters "file+emacs") (org-link-set-parameters "file+sys"))))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-compat.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 14185
  load-with-code-conversion("c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-compat.el" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-compat.el" nil t)
  load("c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-compat" nil t)
  #[257 "\300\301\302#\207" [load nil t] 5 "\n\n(fn FEATURE)"]("c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-compat")
  mapc(#[257 "\300\301\302#\207" [load nil t] 5 "\n\n(fn FEATURE)"] ("c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-loaddefs" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-macs" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-compat" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/ob-eval" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/ob-core" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/ob-comint" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/ob-keys" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-src" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/ob-exp" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/ob-table" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/ob-lob" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/ob-ref" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/ob-tangle" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/ob" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/ob-emacs-lisp" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-version" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-entities" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-faces" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-list" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-pcomplete" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-footnote" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-macro" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-w3m" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-bbdb" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-bibtex" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-docview" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-gnus" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-info" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-irc" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-mhe" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-rmail" "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710/org-element"))
  package--load-files-for-activation([cl-struct-package-desc org (20170710) "Outline-based notes management and organizer" nil nil nil "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710" nil nil] :reload)
  package-activate-1([cl-struct-package-desc org (20170710) "Outline-based notes management and organizer" nil nil nil "c:/Users/sreekumar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20170710" nil nil] :reload :deps)
  package-unpack([cl-struct-package-desc org (20170710) "Outline-based notes management and organizer" nil tar "gnu" nil nil nil])
  package-install-from-archive([cl-struct-package-desc org (20170710) "Outline-based notes management and organizer" nil tar "gnu" nil nil nil])
  mapc(package-install-from-archive ([cl-struct-package-desc org (20170710) "Outline-based notes management and organizer" nil tar "gnu" nil nil nil] [cl-struct-package-desc seq (2 20) "Sequence manipulation functions" nil tar "gnu" nil ((:keywords "sequences") (:url . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/seq.html")) nil] [cl-struct-package-desc org-edna (1 0 -3 1) "Extensible Dependencies 'N' Actions" ((emacs (25 1)) (seq (2 19)) (org (9 0 5))) tar "gnu" nil ((:keywords "convenience" "text" "org") (:url . "https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/org-edna-el/")) nil]))
  package-download-transaction(([cl-struct-package-desc org (20170710) "Outline-based notes management and organizer" nil tar "gnu" nil nil nil] [cl-struct-package-desc seq (2 20) "Sequence manipulation functions" nil tar "gnu" nil ((:keywords "sequences") (:url . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/seq.html")) nil] [cl-struct-package-desc org-edna (1 0 -3 1) "Extensible Dependencies 'N' Actions" ((emacs (25 1)) (seq (2 19)) (org (9 0 5))) tar "gnu" nil ((:keywords "convenience" "text" "org") (:url . "https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/org-edna-el/")) nil]))
  package-install(org-edna nil)
  funcall-interactively(package-install org-edna nil)
  call-interactively(package-install record nil)
  command-execute(package-install record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "package-install" "package-install")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "package-install" "package-install")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Comment: You could upvote or accept the existing answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs comes already shipped with `org-mode`, so you can use it without installing a package.

If you, however, want to use a new version you should remove the existing version from the installation folder (somewhere at `C:\Programs\emacs`). You can move the folder `share\emacs\25.1\lisp\org` to some backup folder (not below the `lisp` folder, you may put it to `C:\backup\emacs\org`), or simply delete it.

The already downloaded package content should also be deleted. Therefore remove the folder `~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-xxxx` (replace xxxx with the current package number). Btw, the folder `~` is your home folder. On Windows, this is the environment variable `%APPDATA%`, or `%HOME%` if you have set that (see [GNU Emacs FAQ For MS Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Location-of-init-file.html) for documentarian).

Then restart emacs and install `org-mode` package.

Comment: I downloaded the zip file and put it in .emacs.d folder as you said. But didn't remove the default org folder. Now it is working fine.

Comment: I did not recommend downloading of a `zip` file, a simple `package-install` should do it after removing originally shipped version. Note that what you did means, that your downloaded version of  `org` is not compiled, which results in a performance loss.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about performance bottle neck.

Comment: There isn't necessarily a performance bottleneck. I often run uncompiled code (particularly when debugging) and performance is acceptable (to me). OTOH, compiling it is a good idea for most tasks. But on whether you see a speedup or how big that speedup is, really depends on your use case(s) - YMMV.

Comment: The current stable version of Emacs is 28.2. If you are running 25.1, maybe it's time to upgrade.